# Get all action names from ViewSet (drf)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it any possibility to get all actions names from `ViewSet` in DRF?
I mean not only standard `list`, `retrieve` etc but custom ones too (defined by `@action` decorator)
I've tried to use `action_map` but it is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to get all the actions specified in a ViewSet class. But, the [Routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) are usually generating the URLs in a similar way. So, I'm going to use the [**DRF Routers**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) here,

```
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter

router = SimpleRouter()
routes = router.get_routes(YourViewsetClass)
action_list = []
for route in routes:
    action_list += list(route.mapping.values())
distinct_action_list = set(action_list)
```

Comment: Shows actions that aren't supposed to be on the list.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `rest_framework version 3.11.2` and there you can do it like that:

```
actions = [action for action in YourViewsetClass.get_extra_actions()]
action_names = [action.__name__ for action in YourViewsetClass.get_extra_actions()]
action_url_names = [action.url_name for action in YourViewsetClass.get_extra_actions()]
```